# Set value of input depending on element clicked in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have made the  following plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Ff2O2TGC4WLaD62fJmvA?p=preview

I would like the value of the input to be the `item.name` clicked.

Here is the code:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <ul ng-repeat="item in collection">
    <li ng-click="edit('{{item.name}}')">{{item.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <input  name="myinput" ng-model="myinput"  />

</body>
```

Js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.collection = [
      {name:'foo'},
      {name:'bar'},
      {name:'foobar'},
      {name:'barfoo'},
    ];

  $scope.edit = function(current_name) {

    this.myinput = current_name;

    console.log(current_name);

  }

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few problems here. The first is how you're passing `item.name` into the `edit` function. Instead of `edit('{{item.name}}')` it should simply be `edit(item.name)`.

The next is `this.myinput` in the `script.js` isn't going to work; it needs to be `$scope.myinput`.

Finally, the `input` in the markup needs to be inside the `div` that defines the controller.

I've modified the Plunkr to work: https://plnkr.co/edit/mslpklTaStKEdo64FpZl?p=info

Answer (score 1):

Angular expression can't have interpolation tags. Correct syntax, like if it was normal Javascript:

```
<li ng-click="edit(item.name)">{{item.name}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call a function.  Just do.

```
<li ng-click="$parent.myinput = item.name">
```